# ¿Como pasar una imagen de una tabla a otra? este es mi codigo

Tags: php, mysqli, imagen

'
//conexion
include ("consultar.php");
session_start();

```
$id1=$_SESSION['id'];


//selecionamos la tabla de origen.
$query="SELECT * from publicados where codigo=$id1";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die("lo sentimos");
$row3=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$titulo = $row3['titulo'];
//aqui tengo un problema y es que la imagen me la guarda en formato de tipo string siendo que en la //tabla de origen es de longblob como archivo binario
$imagen = $row3['imagen'];
$precio = $row3['precio'];
$cantidades = $_REQUEST['cantidad'];

$convertir=$row3['precio'];

$Suma=$convertir * $cantidades;
```

//cerramos la conexion

```
mysqli_close($conexion);
//abrimos otra conexion a otra base de datos
include("conexion-usuario.php");

//guardamos los datos de la otra tabla a esta.
$query2="insert into carrito (codigo, Titulo, imagen, precio, cantidades, Suma) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion1, $query2);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $id1, $titulo, $imagen, $precio, $cantidades, $Suma);
```

'
tengo un problema y es que me guarda la imagen de la otra tabla en dato de tipo string en vez de codigo binario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno amigo lo primero que debes hacer es conocer que es base64 tienes que lograr convertir la imagen en base64

**por ejemplo**

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/wAARCAC4ALgDAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD45xgHkknkknJJ7nPUknJJPWvu6FCNJaf1+J8zOblqxyKCwDEhcjJAyQO9bttvQxRf16DTItTkXSJ7i5sAAUkuo1jkJwN2VBbvnBz6dOlTG9ve0Kdr6Gdt5qxAFPbpVAG3Pb8qLABWgk0NRu7G403Tobaw+y3UKMtxP5hbz2LEq2P4cLgcdcZqEndu977D6KyM4rWlhCbeKQGT4nW3itLeR7yKOXcV8iVSAV/v7s/QY55P1z85jKlT6zGmo+7Z+9frdaW9Nex1YeVT2nIo+7a9+2u3fYm0Al9HtS2CQCCVGBncef8APevVwvwr5mdZe8XyprsMRpTNADStKwCEZ5osA3FLcDQgGljQrzzvtP8Aa/nR/Z9m3yfLw3mbs87s7MY96h3urbde49LamZVC1GsuO1AXG4pbgN2+tKwDc7CpUlWU5BU4IPYg9iOuRzWVaiqqtJG0Jyj8LNkAV08rtqZWF2CqppReoN2ECYpjHxwmWRUX7zEAZOBzwP8A9dAF3W9DufDuq3OnXflG5t2KSeRKsqZ9mUkH8KUZKSTXUbTTsyjtzTEGz2oJDZQAbMe9VYA2UwOf1zR11rW7KxmlSCGWJzukbaobIIb9P6/T5XM63sE6nK5W6JXe/RHdCo6FJ1OVu3Za/wDBL3h9JDokJcKVV5IxInKthjnn8f5V35ckm7Su3q12uradr2ZpjcUq6p01GMXCNnZau7bTeur1tfskuhe2/wCc16+p5QbaLDsNKUhDSmaB3IytOyKG7TnmiyFYTbWYXGlaAuNI607DEEbPwoLHGcAZpE6kZXINOzj1/ApRS2ZtxxM7qigszEAKBkk9AKvYotanpF7omoT2OoW0tneQMUlt51KujDqCD0+lJNSSad7g007PQq7PWrsAuz3NOwDsbjk8n3oJE2e1MBduafQC/oV/FpGqQXc+n2+qRRnLWl3u8t+3O1lP5Gs5RclZO3mNOzu1cpOA7MQAoJJ2joPar6CG7PwpWA5nxbcGw1a0e5QpFLaGOKSRzGuTJ2bHHbr29uK+OxU6VKpUUHqtWr3d2l6vXoj6bCV6mZ+zwznFuNoq7SSu9Lvtru/vNDwrdzz6C1t5/m2kd5LJGiSFowzbdxH5D8hXoZcqEpSqRilOSV31str6dLs8jG4B4epKu4LV8rkle9tlzdbXdvvRplPavoLHmjmtJUgWYxMIXYqshHylhyRn8Rx7il1sVYZFGryIrtsUkAtjOBnk4oBFrXrKzsNZvbbT70alYxSssN2IyglQdG2nkZ96IttJtW8huydk7meVBpWJsKtnJJFJKkTtHHwzqMhc9M0tL2GQbO9BJt6ZHfeF5LDWLnSEuLO4WQW/26EmGfGVYjpnHt3ArNpTvFO1t+5orxs7feYLjcxOAMknA4AqrGZc0TW73w7fG7sZBFOYpISWRW+V1Ktwc9ifzzUuKkrMtNxd0ZxHX+lMDYQYII4I5BHWtSiaeea8neaeR5pXJLu5JZj9aaSSshb7hDayXDFYo2kZVLEKCTtGST+Wcmq06jGBKBbC7adhGjqdzY3VrpyWdibOaGAx3Mhl3+fJvY78Y+XgquB/dz3qEnd3d7/gDtZWRR2+1WkQGwYqklYC/od9a6bqAnvNPi1OAI6m3mZlXJUhWypB4OG/Cs5RclZOxaaTu1coMoJJAwM9K0toK5x/iqwj1bxHbRahJcSW0NrmNYJCWjBY5wBnFfIVIU5Yqo4Rs72bta+l730vZWXXbyPdWE+p0oVny/vFzaNN2Ta95K9nps9bW6M0fAWnSLpGp+Vg21rdAHdKC3zIMcd+h6dM104OdKlio0mveknbRvbW17eel3qefjMbJcmFcnZttLW19Ney6I3NlfRnAXJtXv59Jg0uS7mfTbeV54rQuTFHI4UOwXoCQi5I/uj0qeVXcrb6XKu7WKBT2pkjDHVWHcYUI7Uii5a6vqFpp91p1vdzxWV4UM9tG5CTFcldw74ycZ9alxTabW3ULu1k9yvfafcadcvb3cD206feikUqw9OPpipVmroVmtGRyTzSwxxPM7xR5EaFsqueuPx9KVktQK7Jk0CTLuradZWkGnvZ34vZJ4PMuI1jZfs77mGznrwA2R647VKbbd1a23mU0tLMymQAVbQGwFJq0A9Uq1uBe0nWL/Qp5JtOu5rKaSKSB5IHKFo3Uq6HBHBUkEe5BqXFSVmr/wDA2BNrVMqAcVYC7c0WJFCU7CDaaYAFPpQNC7famkINnI9Pan00D0Oc1X7IPGt2tvdzJarDCDM6BG3YyQOv5/yr4z/aJOTqpRm77apb2ey6Wb03uvM9XL52jTnjIXSeqTs7X6O3VdbOz6MPDMaQ3+qxK3AMThT1I+YZHtwP616GDm/aqnJXunqlomvxu73W51YqhTqYeeIpyUbSsov4rO7voraW1baeqtfU6DbX0J4Bf1DQZ7DTbC+kltnivVZo0inR5FCtt+dQcp7bu3PSoTTbSvp5FNNJPuV9Na0h1G2e+gkubJZAZoYpNjumeQGwcHGecfhTadmloSrX1I7/AMh72d7WJ4bVnYxxyNvZF7AnjOOOeKSTtrqDtfQqFPxosAmCGBBIIOQR60vICTUb671W6kury4kurh8bpZWLM3pz+VSoqKstCndu7KpHt+NMLjdtQSWdJ0e517VLTT7KLzry6lWGKPIG5icAZPTn1qJNRTb6FJNuy6lS6tXtJ5YZV2yRsVYZzgjqK1VmroNjTCcVaQy7Po97Z2NrezWssVpdbhBO6EJJjhtpxzjocU0020ntuFna76lYLTSJuaM97aS6JaWaafHFeRSySS3wdi8qsFCoRnAC4YjH945JwMSk+Zu+9tO3/DlNq22vcobfarIHbDinYBdnPatbAaGj6xc6HJctbLCxuIGt38+BJQEYckbgcH3GCOxqJQUrXvprpoUm0UPK7YqmuhJftodM/si9Nwbn+0gyfZhGB5W3nfu756Yx71jJS5lbb+rFX0d9zz17JpPFesYSG+cFCIWfgjavB47f5618lQqPFVJSUbWbVn5Nq/o7aeR9NmGDeXuFJzjO8Yu8XdLmSlZ+avZ9mrF7wvpzrq+qzGSJESJMxM/7xvnYDj25z9RWuHreyxUaXK3zX1tdK1t30vfQ8HEVkuSnZu9+mnz9TojGCOOK+tsjkuMKYqWhiFKViC1osljbavZy6pbTXmmpMrXEEEoikkQEbgrkNtPXkg/Q1Ek7NRdn5lK11fUpz+W0rtGhSMsSqsckDtzgdqdtNR+hEU9qVgL+jXtpp0873mnR6kjwSRpHI7KI3IIWT5SMlTg4PHHSolFtaOw011VzLaL8qdhF7RdXk0K4nligtrgywSQEXUIlVQ6lSwB6MAcgjpgEdKmUVJWenp5FptGcMoQykhgcgg4INOyFcjZSck8+5pDNgLu7fnWtgJZbiaSCKF5XeGLPloWO1M8nH9aLK9xa7D57Ce1jgeeCSJJk8yIuuBIuSMj1GQenoR2pqz2ewmn16kG3HaqSEO2itLALg00gHKvtS5RXJMcDFVyhcXaG68Gh6sGOEO4gZAB7ntUVdI6ajjpqcZHZpY+K9Zj0rUbXVGkm3i5iMghwRlg+QOnT6g49a/PcLmN4/WMRTdK7tZu7V3ZbX3PeynB4zOIKNKi4zSk+V2vyxTbejt8KutdSvpM0T+No3lJWaaGRMHdlnG1v++cZII4x09vVpzl9ahy21fn28vMqnHD+xqe3bXu+7a3xab67W7eR2hj68V9afPDWixVWEMwQfakIYy9eMfWp+QDdgIqbAIU7j8qVgGlOtIBjD/8AXSYDSgPf8qViyMqM0rAXptbuZdCg0kpB9khne4VlgQSlnCggyY3FflGATgZJAyTUcq5ubv5/psVd2sPHGK3TsFxwJ4yKq7JuWrrVLq/itorm4lnjto/KgWRywiTcTtUdhkk8epPeqUYpuytcd29+hBwfpVWQh6qvrzV2QD1iyfX6VSj2EaVrqIttHvLE2VvK1w6OLmRcyxbc8KfQ55+grNx95O70v8x9GrblHZx7VZNhfLpqOuomw2bSDjgEHNceLUnBxi7N9f110OzC1IUqsalSKlFO7jsmuzs07fNHA+A9KXXRqJFqzxy3T4UFwzkscKOf8/ia+RoezVLmqNab/Lr0X+R6WLrKmnUj7id3ZXsk+muvl5lmUWGmfELSILvcqiUxu0BLPkowUMOx3YyOOMEDmniXKnVg8LZttbt2t119PxOGo6tTDN0LNvu9Pw8r2PRIp7FNDubeSyaTUJJ43hu/MwI41D71298kqc9tvvX2nLK6d9P+Gt9xw3VrNfMzvLAIyOM84q7ElvXP7OuL8vpVpPZ2exAIriYSvuCjcdwVeC2SOO4GT1qIqSXvO/orencbavpoZhiI7Zot5CGGIjnGKXKA0x+2KVgLusz2N21qbGxayEcCJKDLv8yQD5n9s+lZqMle7vr/AEim09lYy2jI7U7El2bV5JdDt9LNvbLHDO84nESiZiyqCC/UqNowp9T61ny+85X3VjS+ljMK496dhCFcdqQGl5JxitrAKIj6Vdn1EHln/IpgO2VZIbDn/CnFPYTY5c1bESBjVWHceJD3xRZhcesnYjNN6yasDdrD21L+zrK9lECzf6NKNrKD/AenuP6V4ebUadTCLnk48rvo2r2810v02NaeGljK0YQu2tfdvd211tufPdj8RfGVhoL6ba6tex6Qlwt6YUB2CYDar8Dg4zz9a+EmnUhytXT0eienU+lnSp1IuE46PddC74f1rxH4h8S6DYmzlubtrxGTEJEtyWOBn16nn3PWuOs4YSE62IqONO2vRRS7W2+XkepUzfDZdhaEpUoRjh25Xa3V1pK+jiu1ttD3hoHjdlkXa4JDLjpjrX6xhOWcFKLumk1b0Vnc+EqTVR86trtb79BpiPXrXRs7k9AWIk4A5PAHrSsA+8sJrGd4LiJ4Zk4aORdrD8KlWautQd07Mn0nRo9XmnR723sRHA8oa4JAcquQgwPvHoP51E9FdJu7RSV+pmmAdqbiiSJ4lHrWTSGMaIEdaXKguRGH3qbFF2+vYLvS7G0j023tprbf5l3EXMlxk8b8nHA4G0D3zWag02273BtWStsZbRH0/CqdwNraO610L0KLd1o93YRWstzazW6XUfmwNIpUSJuI3L6jIIz7VUWpXSe24mmt+pW+zHPX8CK0UXcRoNY6d/YkMiXU7asZ2WS2aFRCsWF2sH3ZLZ3DG0DgHJzTjCbk0lpbv1+79Q0sUDbMByv5U1F72IsW7DQr3VTMLSzmujDGZpBEhbYi/eY46AetObUbc2l9Fcai3sVfs/8As4q0/IiwG3HXBqraXCwiwfNVKN5P5Ey6Fb4gaTqPhbRdQS+tZtPuvsPnok6lG8uSPcj89irKQfcV4GY8lXCO9mr2763/AK+Z6mDq1cNiFOlJxlbo3ezVt/Pb0Z5n4DR5vDMLtocVzYGWUXUsoTLx4HK5PUfMe3Qc9a+LaryhL2EE7LS76+fkevi/ZQwqlQnes73TXu2sra3vdu6atpZWMfx3fvaXMUX9nCy+ztiC7WQeaACCuSAPm2kfXrRUUrKNeKd9+q/4b1WxhRiq0FGq1ro+2p7lZSrc2sUqtuDxhgw75ANffZbUlUppzVnbZO9vTQ83H06FKtKGHm5wWzatf5akzRDHI/xr1JU9b/8ADnAhCu0ggkEHIIpOKEO1O9udWu5Lq8nkurmTBaWZizHA4yax5FFWStYq7b11KhQ9hTsK5G6Hjjj1FQ0xlt9HQaINR+3W5kM5h+x5PnAYzvxjG38fwrnd+blt036FW0vczDGO3NOxI3yMjPAqbLcq41oCBnt7UrDI2jPPHvRZgbIUemK1UmWWJrmW5WFJZXkWFdkau2Qi5JwPQZJ/Ommk7pCu2KkanuR+NdCSfkSTpbqccj8avkV7JhcsRWcbegJ9DXRCjF6/qS2zT0u81DRDctpt9PZNcwtbzeRIV8yNvvIcdQaqphYSS5knZ3+YKTV7O1zLOnMue/1rT2ck7Nf19xJG9iRnK5+lS4PW6/r7hDfsfXirpwUXKTW9rfqLd2OS+KrGLwVqTS7neRFhXOWOSQAB+X6V8hnMGsPFKTjZ6ro9X5P8NfM9rLK0KUpqdNT5o2TbfuvfmVmtVqtbqzemx594X0O0Ph6N11TUUZcrdWloTwrZVSoxz/XpxivlY1KVGKUm1frbRJee337noTo81KeIc4pQte7s3ft5K2vYy/FHh6xNkrpf3sl1MHl8i8YtsjC5XOV+8dmOP/ZadRU6kE4u9/Uxp1L6o9k8L3lpf+G9LmsIpIbdrWMBJnDNwoU8gDuDX1uR1Kn1HkrTUpJ62Vra6K129jw6tDEUXF4neV2nayau1pq77Wv1/A6WHTYJNGub19Rt4rmGaONLFlfzZVYNudTtK4UqAQSD8wwDzX0Mm/axTW93f0tpvf8AA57Llbv8ikYgetaqn7t2F9SNo+CetZuOgE2u6S+h3McL3Fvcl4I5t1tIHUB1DAEj+IZwR2IIrlTurpNWutdNv60KejsZjHI+lUTcjwTnvWVrlXZd0V9PhuJm1O0uLqEwOsS28wiKylcIxJU5UNgkcZwQCOtZSjJ25Xb1X39hprqrmeYyARim10Aad3UDP4VDSKGODjJWh97DNDa69Rx7V1Wa3FckVsY5I/3hVpoLjwc8ZxVcq2vYm5dTTrv+zjfCCX7F5nlGfadm/GdufXFJWT5b672Hra9hqSsmOTiurladkRcsxX3QE/nVxlrZsdy2t4rYHHHeutVYWS00I13JlZJeeBWvNGbvdINi1daJcxaTb3zWzi1mkeNLjadjOuCyg9yAR+Yp4uNOOXUpxactb23V5aXXydghfnbfy/U8p+OjG10HTYlcI0t/Hxzg4Gf618DxPGpRrQppLl+d72T2t6s+hy6OHlRm5N+0urWS5bWd766O9rdLX10RR0B5o7LRpN9lp7RlUt5ZZH+rSyKqFtoGTxyuN3UgV8pWnH6pNuHtNH7tleXlrprtqzHFL91NuDnpsra6bK7tqLr9vptr4Us79L3fqtzqEp1CCRcJBlQFZHxuO5i+YyuF2qwY7jg9rCmo01pfZW2tvsttuvod+GwU50ZV6atGFk9k1fay36a2269DS+EsSS+ALBhctNOJJVdHQqY8NwM9/X8a+gyJzcaqcFFXun/Not10t6nkY2viq1X2dbWENIO90k9WrdFdt+vqdhJGBj29a/QKkEnH9TyY6piNgjvUpJxQ+pDIGwcZA+lYyvbRfgNWKzQkkn9KxcQBbc9WHFZ8rWrRWgIi5xsOPas1DXRD5h7+Uf4SpHUkVnJLpoUmMEUROdwI7jvXPyp63K1Levy2FxeCTTrJ7K38tFEUknmHeFAY5wOpyfxxU8koq0nf+tC203orGU8WQTjHb0qm3vYmx0P2PtgE+4rpUWtNx2QNZbhnaCPaulJtXS2/rsToRPYpg4wD6EVv7KNrp2/r0M22MdpltTbCZxblvM8nd8u71x60uSMXzf1+RN3axXCOvQ8emapQlbRkprqO5xk4I9615Xa7YroeuMjGR9K6HRS1X9fiTzE8Usin5ZPwq4SqQd4yE2uqNGPWrp7KG1a5doI2Z1hJ+VWOMn9B+Vae2qTwsIKV3101te/dXLi9X2PI/wBo6ZL3RdNX7fDHJFK0i2RDeZKWAUshAx25Bx7Zr8u4qxsp46FGMW42vdWsnZXvs9bdFZW00SZ62XzlTtDkbTvrpZW2vrf0t21OHsNI1RtGkuBo13LLtHlMpuyqR7fm5XgdOnPXtivm4RrOSsk42369LW6bXufSXw31eTlJqpdWsla2t7677W8r9kSat4b1rUYio8O/YRsw0kstyinoN+ZiFyP5Giu3Ss5Le3R9fS9v0FhKEsXzRpyS5U5atLZdL7vyWr7NnXfs9X5OmalZztl4J1ZUY5JBU5Oe44H+TX2PCc6VPEupON5JP7tW+mttL99jysyr1vq31VS9xu9vPo/0+Z62LdXt5cDpg9Olff4OnGGXV1a9nF+mvo/0Pm6jfPFEmjvZ2mqWk1/bNe2KSq00CybDKgPKhsHGfWsK8bxag9Wt+i+Q4tJptXIZrdJZ2Mce1SSVGcgCoWjSSv1/rQF3GrYD7zELjtikqakm5af16BrsiCRQOnOPauaXLfTWxauaGpy6S32Y2EcqDyV87zyDmT+Irj+GsYzum5pf8ArS6tczyEk/hDY9O1Cs+l/0HcY0KDlIwcevFYzUVrFbDu+pXl3ljmLaPWsHdvVD0AxqygkK2PQ4osmr2uVY9J8O+Xod5PM1hZ6ms1rLbiK+VmVC6ld4x/EucivQeGWIcVGdtnfbrs9P6RSlyXbV/wCvUxJNHdMhWz/snkV6v1SSTUZX8tXuvQwv3Kz6cRkt8o9SOKy+qzjeUlZd7aBdPRala408YyHDexFVUwyspRlfurE311RSmtGU424P5VdSlOD5ZKz6rb9DLTdDrGJoLyGV7dbpI3DNBKSFcA9DjnFOOGr1VyQum/wFzJO7HahEt/f3M1vbR2KSSFltYSSiA/wjcScD3NXCjUmuWLu/xf4Wv8hSave1il5ToecZHrWDhO9n0AsJ8pAYfiDXQ5eyqqnPTfb0CLWrR4t8aIm1nxtplmsfmC3tV3qvBbc54B/vc8V+SZs6lTHzU7aWt91313u3r2PsqLwyw1P2CalZ812rc13qtNrW0fU2vD/g3T9RubpL+4vGF1KyxTQXLRxO2AxhI/vAE/XDDqOdsFg4Vm1KVu3nton879Fo7XdkefWrOOz/AAE8X+ALK3WSex+2S/YwfOnnuGlRpdu5Lcf7Rzn2xjqTjnx9Ghhq6w/PeTTdr3fS+z6XSfbZ2d0TSxUXJU3JJvW3V2dn52V/xRjfAtZLLxxqdtOqx+YjuVB3YIwT/wCh4Bq8mlKlj4WlZK99L3Vn+ba11/y9GvOgqFRVYOUmvds7cr5lr1vomrab+R76YRLGwAAX0r9hjSWIoyUFZaafifHydpq+5DLGGwqrXPVj7W1OMRLTVliOzeDllwMZBNb1Mur4f36kbLdf137r7ylNPREcqlgQBwa45Upa26l3RW8gMfmGfSso0dfeVwZDJbHJBTC1g7Xs42+//IPmQi3dG/doKwb5X7iKXmSM86FlaIZ9fSlNVYtxlGz/ACK0eqZVleUsSFIA9KyUZyu0thaELPKO3HpioakuhXMjuft3lnOTn1zXUpcrum/W5puTx3r3GQ21vcdq7YOpXbU7Pz7fiQ2o7ENxt9d2auUmmtb/AHdCPwGadcWtjqlvNcWwvYI5FaWBm2rIvdcjpXRGpyXjD4n10a+6zQuqb+4o3+yaeWSKMQxliVjBztHYU5UXq73tuZ3RnsWyQgpRpuzUES33InLM3ArSb5novzIRo2Mem3OnXgvWnivlCi1aJQY2Ofm8w5449K1VsQ4U5RUbfa1/FddR3STdyolnIrklee1c9RVIVJSktvL/AIAJJpI8e8f6es3xGtJxeq4eKIMI2/1O1vmDZGBxz/wIV+LYnEvE4uqnFrlklr10Turfdd9T6LCTcoyi4tcr+T63W91+qJZmkb7PFo+rT/ZLmTz5ri6aPytwYDzlQjcRkKM8DPIztatasVUpunF2TXe3zX4f0jvwlaWErwxEEm4O6UkpJtPRNPRrumn6E2oadqHhqa80HxRdXdpJYndEyyqqBnyPNkUc/wARBP543VMVTbUprVLR9k7XW23fvZHNUpxnU9o1r6a6vW3lotPJGR8LJINF+JaeVItxLdxeQqMwdW3xHLcd8rx3HHHFY0aU6teEab1covR8t9V1Sfpba2jNquHw+LhyYqpKEFreKu9NUrNx0b0eux9CW2lzPAd52q2OO9f0RgMDiJYKcJvlU+XvfdeX9PyPj5Sipaa2ubuieC7vWxeyWEaS/YbdrqcySKmI1IBIz16jgVdepgcvqU5avmdk3f8A+RHGNSqnbpq/QyvsrS8l8/8AoVVz+39+dS9vW/5EbbEZ07I4NeVPDwkrxlr6P/I25mv6/wCCT6ZoNvd3RS6vEsIhFI4mkjLAsFJVePUgDPvzXk16DoxUoxb1XRryvql01NYvm0bsZrWGeuSfpzTVJNJPW/SzuJyY37AUOSMf71RUpcl21a3dv/Iad/MilsmdsZNcUouTsv6/AvQt2ml6e2m3jXMk6Xw2/Z1jAKNz8249uPSkqUm1bRLf+rFK1nf5GY2nJ0yDUNLa9/69B2LKsC2SCuP0oVm72tYNSxHJjABrsjJJJIhjt0jZ2t17d66+eV24vf1J06ob5E5UjaSfUVajV5Wkm/Qm8dxv2ScHkP8A8CFbvD4qlrKMte6ZHNF7WJFsZOm3n/cranOrFWS3/ur/ACJaX9f8OPOksp6N/wB816ksDVi7KLfy/wCAZ8yBNLI/gf8A75ohhKi3hL/wH/gA2gSAwZXBPI7dK+cnTnRpz01Vuh0JqTVz5tSS01/xxfFrZ5tl46pbxjcHlCkEbfTKjntycdq/F6XPUqP2is2+m39fl5n2WLWHp/7q242VnKyfS+zenz1Vj0iw8AW19ol8kOkiO1tSx1G9NuF82bYWWNHb5go6nvj5e5r28NQoyrPCQneo1KVnZO0d+W+vKrpvRPW3meNjM1ozq0qDUYTUbJK92r/E99bu1/8AglrUPCml3VmLW6t4Y5/KE1jeiDLq+AxjLLyTj7ueq5GRtFdGPw0sJCnCpScnKyTjy+6pLmvKzv2srNtO2nKcUsVKMo8sea7s9dvPXppr+TuePWM8Xhb4k6XesjBoJws0WCoVy5H8iORj0xmvnW5Uqikle2vrbofRU+WpHlm7J6Xte2vbqfVEevQAxqbdlZcgj0xX9DYPHU5Tw6lRcZJSutHayu7a+XVeh8hiqcKdWpGlPmgnZPa66aa7jhrlqFZhDIq9CR0/nXVKvle0qT/r/t45l7Tuv6+Q3+3rAY/dyA+wo+tZWtVTa/ryYv3ndDDr9kPuxSE/7QrjVbLOkJP+v8SK/edWQvr9vjAjlPtgf41lOeCtaEZ6dGo//JFJy6v+vuJtNuxqYuyJ4rXyIWlH2htvmY/hX/aryHXlF+7B66K1/PX4jVJPdpWMttWmcnbFg/7XFYVYVpN2hb1dv1CMorqRvqVzJnlF/wCBVg3Xm200vn/wSk4ld9QnAPzJ+tYv2tnr+L/zK5kV5ryZsndUTUnq3+f+Y1I1oZSn8BIrKm3u1c1aLMd3CPvxEf8AAa7YOin78bfIh83Rlg3Vo4zjafpXVN4WouZJp/h+ZK5lpuTw3tog3MWGOM+X3rroVcFG3PLVf3V/n+hElN7L+vuLC6zFxzkdfuivYjmNWa5XK69I/wCZjyxWtvz/AMi3qviw6veveTlHnYKCFhVBgDA4H0qViXSilSbfk1F/jzXG7Sd5f1+AaVcya7qdvp9jCs13cyCKKJI/mdj0FWs0wlJNvlSSv8Fv/bmCpzbSWtytNdxbmQ3KRbeCgXoa654nDVI8sMTGMeyj/m3/AJGfvJ6xKl1dWNtEZZrt/LQeZIU2sdq8nHvXyvEOJhhsuksPU9pUtom1Z6t2uk2nfd699mjWPtG26cU2loru21lrZ2XnrY+ZPh/4m0LQdSu74Xc51aa7kjRnty4jtmBy+1er85xnGQO1fh+ExNeGIi5Rsravezf3d7rZbaH3rwuHllntqlS1a6XJZtWtvzeqsesn4neH7bSZLS1j1QQ+SQFaxkOWw3JOOvJ59ya+zWYYeCvThqotK9m7O/l1um+7V12PlfqrlNTlZtdfL/LReWhTPxD0O+0+OCa31RlMSL8lhISCAMFT7Y4NVPNYVIqNRN2SXTokt3tto+nazK+rSTuu7/G5414u8U2954pjnuUMyxXBMwKmBp4vlI4I+RuD+JNfGYyc6iag7Sd7O11d91p6nrKlJ0pKm7N7Pezt2v8A5H05p97YarZ21xHG6JLGJFU8lcruINfveQYzBZjgcPCpeUoKzaS3V3JPayunprv8z5nG4LFZdVdPEK0mlLVbqSTTtfZp6epfTWZLfSbjTYQVsriVJpYj/E6Bgp/Dc3511tYVTjVhQ1Xd9P6X9anHednFvf8AQoM/+wo/Ku5Yiooq0V11tH9UZtLv+YkVvLeSiOCNpZCCQqKSeBk1x1cTFq7svw/QtRey1K7Jzz1rlc0OxGQc4Gc/7NcLrNOyf3f8MXYjKEn3rjlUu+39ehpYY0R+o9q5edp3L5R0dnLPHLJHE7pEN0jKMhATgE/pTdVaJ6XDl7Fcpx0rC7KSOvjsJwucxsPTcK1pxrxi2nFr1ibe63bU0rxvt1lYwSW9pCLWMxiSJVV5MsTlz3POPyrWEVBuUmtddWnbS2is/wDhxO7SS6ev+ZTfSrXnJAPs3/1q9qX9nO7bt83/APIGHLU/pFjz0TRzprXLCzMvnmLH8eMZ6VUYZRb2lSTUvn/8iJ+2typfkZTWlup4kbH0rz+Vxdoy/L/IejWwqxwJxulIP+yK9KnUUfdvKz3XLH+v6sZtJ66CpLaRMCiTEjkHpiqVfLE0owlJedv8ibVd72I8WrHIt5G/3mqYvASd/YSdvP8A4AfvOsvwMD4hXy2Pg7V5ooTCUtJMNz/EMf1r53iutD6rGOFpctn1vs7bXW9n89D1cphQlXf1uTUbPZJvmtot1pe132+4+dfhXZzPqsLrqLaLI5HkSvEGLfOVHPpnKk8Yr8moOft4Rgr8zSvolHzvfa/3dT66nh6FWhWlWrKDhG6TTbm7r3VZaaa66Huz+DfFflyJJ4tuCrAqQ9mhK9jjvnmv0hZbimnGddpeafS19N/yPjPrEN1D8Sa18H+IIrq2a78U3c9vAy7oVt408wDGVJ69sCrrZVXV4zxL00vbeys+qemy8trDWJhuofj3+XXqeLfGaztx4w1OSyea9ga4850k+7CCxQRhjycHanfofSvz7GU1Srygpc1nvtf+vK67Hv0Jc1NPa/Q9q+Fz3MvgHSJp4GR/I8v94h52MV4/LH4V+m8H5rSp4WvGFpShZPq03rsk9fhavY+azCKqV7c1/n5Xs/kdSd+eY/8Ax2vuZZpNv3of+S//AGp5igujGlZFHTH1CioWaVYK0dPlFf8AtpXImPsbq90q6W5s7lrS4UECSKQKwBBBwfpkV4VSjKa5ZpPybRrGVndafeVWiLks0gLE5JBzUuLvdyXy1LXoRGEdfmb6LXmN631fyNPIuWWozWFlfWsVvE8d5GscjSwK7qAwb5GIypyMZX3HQ1zShzNSSen/AA23U0TsntqZzwlTzER9TUuLTs42BFi1vb2ztrq3tppIYLpRHPEjMFlUEEBh3GQDz6UKnzNPlu1t/wAAd7JpPcqNG2OFxn0Wm3K2i38v+ACSLi/KOlZ2haxV2TLOwAwAfwrRNWVvyYamrpNtPqUF7Kktvbi2h8zEowZOQNqerc5/A10LE1NPZwvfS/Lt6sEk73dra6kDXF4jFWhCHuCMVvUqYmEuWcLfKxFotXTuaOkeIbzSLwTi2tLn5GTyriMOvIK5+ozkV21cViZxULpeiX6ER5U77kSand53bLUfWMVUcXX0k4w+aX5kuCfVj11ORAS8Vu59oh/hXLHGzjrOMX/26v8AIbgns2vv/wAx39qs/wDy6RZ9krr/ALUlJWWHhf8Aw/8ABF7NfzP7zgPjbrMNj8O7xb2CaNbhkgQxEcsSSMg9srzXxHE2LxNTLcNShBRs3dvqr62SW6sddCnU9onRae179F1tbrZnlXw+t86ZaqpigAXbI9wobcGUsVxu5VvM6f7XrXxtGTjqu39f5H0FZe7oe5Wmu6KmpR6LapffurceXPfuM3BUYkUd9yEjggErhu5r6vJc1agvrNJxeul1f0ejV1dWsrWWx4DpzrU1Nx5W9090/lpb5/Mh8WX5it3ttPXzL6Rd2yJkEiJnBKg4+c9FHXqf4a6s6z2ClFU46zdkkr2v1dopK/otddzKMVQceZN3dtE97dbbLu27bdzwnx/axw6bM2fNcQsqskYR0ZNrqCDkqFGRk46Z9a+Mr2vofRUr7Hf/AAK1xtV03VbW6vZpPs11vgZzu/dygvxzx82Tgepr6TherSwmInJNwcnq0tXpa+++3XVHBmMHKKW56mtlaS9Lok+64r9G5cDNXjiHfzTX6P8AI8Pkkt4/j/wTRsIILK3v4mtILv7TEIlllk+aA7g25MY54K89iaxqUKTkrO6TvpKOvlfl266FLRNNb+TM99JAGQyj6sKwnOVtGlf+8v8AIFFX/wCH/wAxBp0K8NOo+lSnFbzX4f5Dt2Ra0z7FpF0Z3WK/UxPH5E8RKgshUNwRyM7h7gcGs6+GwvKmsQ29No/5uxUZST1ivvMx44UY4eR/TK1wTnSjJ8rbXTS3+ZaT9CzG2l/2Vc+bDO2o+YnkFceVswd+7vn7uMe9cbmlJNRTWt7/ANepavZ3M9sdVRU/Cq547pW+QrPqRu7AE+Yqn0FZ+1v1RfL5Gilio6OPwAry1Wa6/wBfcdXIi9d3KXOnWloUgjFtu/exrh3yf4j3xVKpZtuW/wDWmgcqslYpJZxn7sp9eDTU29n/AF9xPKuqLVxo01pFA9xHIkc6eZE0i4Ei5I3D1GQfyrZTbuk72Bq3SxCLVI268/WutSUX/wAFGfKTJuj+7s49a6o1qkNraeX/AACHFGhYXNqsN4LyFndosW5hZYwkmRy3ByMZ44rqqY2vNJRcVr/LFaetjNU4q99fmzPkMu0Zn49pMVlLE1WknP8AGwKEex4v+0veKvhrSrU4leS4dgJJOmE6j35P5CvjM7xDqU6KUrpc2j7vl1T6ap9NkrdT6HAKjHDzjKD9peNpJ6JWldW6t3Tvdf5ZHgi1nR/tkFxo8EiRCNWl1FkfH3fQ9Nvt1rzKK0TTSfqTV7NXLvjCW6sLKTUlvNF82ExuHTUZZp/MUjYyDaBkZYe6s2a3q+6r3T873/qxlD3tLNfIueBjB4hXXdW13xBptrq/llrGCKV9jSF1HJDDanlE7Ww33cbcsxGFCcq05XSVnu3ZO/a19tvv0OzEYeFGlTnGak5atLda21uktd1bpu7lDxraS3Fgbm51DRb2TiJis8ryKpUrxnHqO/YcdqqvSajzOSfpe/8Akc9OonKyVh/7MWt2lnq2prqdgl6JbQqsTSFGLBcKePQuG9+lPKZyhib82llpb0v/AJeR142VJ4VQ5PfTvzX6W2tt89z2PzSpwAoPpX3P1jWyVj5blZZtLO91K4itrWKWaeVgkcUYO5yewFae+4tu6XXoTbW25XktnR2WVxGynBBJyDTSju5W+bDXovyGkW8ZyXZj6AUSrYeD3v6Byyexb1XVrfVbv7SbSG3OxE8uBdifKoXOPU4yfrXJCrQgrWb9W/8AgGjUm77ehnvdxx/cjAPrUSxUE/djYag3uyMXDfxN16KK4XiJW1ZuoocksbbS292J9OtYfWNbu7/rY2UC5rdpa2kFi1pKlzLPEZZERWBhbJGw5AycAHIz1ohXve0bWv8Ad9wSppa3uVxcPz94/lXLcsvaRNYLPJ/aQuPJ8qTYbfG7zNp2Zz23YzSd7afiCiupXW7A4xtH0rqTS8jMsXGtS3McS3FwzpCvlxh2JCLknA9Bkn860Uoq7elws3oaei6VZa5NZ6cdSj03xHeBpLLT9Uj8iK/jxuU29wT5bsR/C/lk8bd2a4ljowfvR/X71b77I19i5LR/LYu6i3hv4d6ZqsuvatouoX0kbWUMFnO1zJaTpcQxXJMStGTNEkpZVZgjbSNzbWrz62Zvenp+v4f8E3jhkvi1/r16fcUINS+Ht94b/wCEgsvF9zJpzSNZRQXdklvdm8EiIEMQmZfLKMXEm/8AhZcbgAbp5vLl5bbvvp67f8N89B4ZN3v0/rqTeJ08MRXV9FoF9JNcafdJa3EUk6T7y0KyeYjKqgYJIK4OOBuPNdGXYhuq3JLZ/f8A8Df5GdejGEdD5u+P1xBr3ijw5parCHtWVp5AcNtkk53ewVf1rxMXD/ap1VNtStppZW7aJ6+r8rG2EoSoOUpSb5rWT2Wm6663vq2dl4T1Kx0PSA7PbyWsmGxtXegA3cd8YavVw+JVKnytXvbpqrdr+u3X5Izq0nUldaNf13NqytoPGs0N1DHJJZwk4h8jAKMFKt65f0xwnHWQ1MJ1sRiZRcP3aSs922730t6ddvPfnj7WFSUZJKNk076t3d01a2mnV3b2VhdX0uXw/qsUsFnhwSsUBG3epyWtj6d3j9G3L0NddWnKlU5ZR17evT9V81btqpKSvf8Ar+tzM1fxFbeJ9AufsNz9ns2iMi5jKvMynOMEfLyuK4ZYqNaMqcdLeW/4W09Tvng54eNOvJp8+yTV1bTVLZvfzWx5N8J5j4f+KDNPnbcSyWUbMMjB3bF9v4a8/DtU6if9a6fqaVk5wsv66n0irtKyoMfOcDIAr7OHLDVHgO8nqX57W+8N65LbiQxXtlMR5tnIsgV1PVXXg/UGsXiHJWSdn0/4DNFSs9Xt/XczbiWQSNuZix5+brn6VvPEP4U/0/AhU+ojwuIEleJvJYkCQjCkjqM/iK53NSdmPlaRZ0Xw/f8AiS6lh0y2894o/Nk+cKqJuC7mZiABllH1IFY1atKm7y0/r0KjSc3ZamP4t17RvhXdXEPjOHUIb0QxTWenWCqXu0cuC/nElERShycMSWACnDEeHicwcXan/X4HoUsPZe8ccv7T3hzeIk8Ax2lrJGViu01eZ7tGxjdISuxvm7CNcjjI+9XnQxlSMk7m8qcbWsel33h3XbHw5ouuXdrNFpWrQiexu1dHidTnK7lJCuOcocMO4FfRUcS8RFJyvbp29Pn2OKdLk1tuYjyNkjzCeKtu2/5kXZYU85UYH1rG/Y15e49nZlOWA9iearmdhWRLZiGa7ghnvIbGORghuLjcY0/3toYgUTrciuCp3Zoax4Qu5/C+qXmmRweJjarKzT6BqFvdLDtUFDKnLLg7t24DjGO9edPFN6L+vwN1SS1PL/GHxwNn8M4vCw0x471f45ZY720iZcnzreKeJ5bWbJXd5cij/Z7149WTjqdMVpY8A1HxDcNqtxcCMRrO5kWNR8uWzkD8a86UnJl6Idql9KlpFbSyj9y7KAo+b5jzz9VFJScXYbVmeufBb4haQ0d3o3iPUb2yv9QubcWF7aafDc/vNpQrNumjOzlPu57k/d2n0KWIcNU/6+4mVNTRyfxFhuNO+OGuWM1xHdRabeywedB8qSeQpjDrg5wWJYVrDlWkVZN3+b1v82deIr1sVJVK8uZ2S13tFWS+SVl2R0enade3VnFo9gZpjLLtndpfkfIyEbHJQD55D0wFT+LjtpSU5OlF6q11fZP/AIY56mGq0qEcVKLUJNpPu1ZtLzV1dHsuhxQ+FtIgsbCW5ijgi2GQyfPI38Tsfc547Zx2r6CnUeH1otx807ev/A69NbHjSfP8SuJqUMWt2E9reuZredNjgnr6fr/LNJvnTUne/wDX5kpWd0tjyi40KXTLq8srxlitMKbpSSkMinKJdKvQKxIWQfwuAeM142Jp1KCSUb3t5aPqv60emmy9nBqhXlL2s+WybTs3qlotNrnnFtFqGieLppInZRE8N4VZQ2OkbZJ6HG6vOnTVRWd909G1qndbenzOvD4qphJe0p2vZx1Sa1TT3X/DeR9QeYpLY+UHkc5+lfU0211PnJIVJePvsBnnBq5VFazZKTIi5UnIDH/a5rO7T11KbuWJtWu59Oi09rmQ2UUjSx2+47EdgAzAepCr+Qp3V72sS72seafGrW5IPClvp8Ojq2+5+0S6sskm9FVcLCFB2Y6tlgT93kc58THuUpXR10EreZ4HOJCFcxFlByCRwfb+VeIk+p3XsVngVZ0QOqPJz5eDlCT0/Orsrg2epeB/iLfeALKbStUkmu9LE6SzWMcoQysuVyrEHYdrEA4PXoa6Y1XT1Rk1fc7LWv2rRa6jItj8OfCMVl96KK5+2yyqh5UPILldzYxztX6CiWLrLr+Q+SPY9M8K/tAeCPibYa3Z+JfAkngXX7a3Zra/0eV2tHuFOBE8UhJAx1IPbODxT+syj1/r7jf2SfQx/DGq6XresXNnq/iLS/C1rHGzxX+oGV4pnyNqfu42PIOc47HmtVjpEOgmcnefFGztrm5ijjaYRxkxSxElZHyRjsdpABz156U3im2WsOkv6/zMez+KPha109Nc0o61ofjWwlZ7PUNMljEKSgnaWz8+OuQOucc5Nc9Sd9SeTlZ534q8bXPjW8ubvVXhGoSs0jTQQJGHZmyQVQBFHJxtAAHGAK4pyuUtjjELTyYnnECk43bd2OnPt0/+tXOtxosNcQfbgSqvbxR7nMnBOPu/jnH607aFqKuMWaxmK/uzFOSNpZ/kA9Dken/6qzVypU9C7ca4IbYi2lSZgpDbUIZQepGR0ranOZnY9C8J/tJeN/A3ha10jRNVg0JIMr9o02xgiuH7/NMqb25+bluSa6I1JXuS27Wvsd/qH7VOj6lpzXt94Rk1HxTe5N3M119lso5MAb44kUs2T8zFmHOeMV2QxFSKsn+Ri4Rbu0Ys37RGlT6TZWsXh24ttWjyZ7sXwlhnG7tH5YKcY/ibPtWzxdVf0v8AIn2MWYWrfFtNcsriO7sGhmVt1vJE2NqcbkfI5Vuh4/lWUsS5LX+vwCNJJ6HncmueZq8j2McogmR4RHcS/MmfmAOOv/6qz9pc6VGx6TYfHS/gsYI30mOR0RY9wlPzY4zjFbLGygrI5pUFNnQeEPH3in4g6x/Zfh3w0up6gYml+zwSEtsTlm+g60RxUqjstSasIUY802kl16dF39F6kPjLxf40+HmpwaVr+hR6VfGFJhFcAlij8q/Xv2rOWJb2ewU4wmuaLT+fbf7jmrj43a1yqx2SheCfKJx6d6X1qVrf1+RapK5ma38VNV1nT5baaO0aOQf6t4M+uDWP1pz3/r8CvZpanm2r6hdaipup8Iw+6Il2qMDA+nrRdSNFFCaLezS3aXcrs3kgDzGGe3A/kazlIVi7fatHeXcskpdyWDNIWxknNZbhY6X4f+BW8c6lPNNdCw0i1jL3V24DYIyFRASN7scBUHJ7DiuqnT9xvov8/wASNz//2Q==
```

este codigo puedes visualizarlo en este link copias todo el codigo y presionas generate image y te generar una imagen.

https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

y la base de datos mysql de tipo longblob acepta esto vale..

si la imagen te esta guardando en tipo string estas haciendo algo mal busca como generar una imagen en base64